# Slow array operations

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab

I'm a quite new MatLab programmer, so this might be an easy one.. :)

I'm trying to generate a script, that will be able to read any number of XYZ-files, in any order, into a array, and arrange them in the array according to the X and Y coordinates given in the file..
My attempt is to use Load to get the files into a array, and after that, read through the array and, as explained, use the X and Y coordinate as the locations in a new array..

I've tried presetting the array size, and also I'm subtracting a value from both X and Y to minimize the size of the array (fullArray)

```
%# Script for extraction of XYZ-data from DSM/DTM xyz files

%# Define folders and filter
DSMfolder='/share/CFDwork/site/OFSites/MABH/DSM/*.xyz';
DTMfolder='/share/CFDwork/site/OFSites/MABH/DTM/*.xyz';

%# Define minimumvalues, to reduce arrays.. Please leave some slack, for the
%#  reduction-algorithm..
borderX=100000;
borderY=210000;

%% Expected array-size
expSizeX=20000;
expSizeY=20000;



%# Program starts.. Please do not edit below this line!
files=ls(DSMfolder);

clear fullArray
fullArray=zeros(expSizeX,expSizeY);

minX=999999999;
minY=999999999;
maxX=0;
maxY=0;

disp('Reading DSM files');
[thisFile,remaining]=strtok(files);
while (~isempty(thisFile))
    disp(['Reading: ' thisFile]);
    clear fromFile;
    fromFile=load(thisFile);
    for k=1:size(fromFile,1)
        tic
        fullArray(fromFile(k,1)-borderX,fromFile(k,2)-borderY)=fromFile(k,3);
        disp([k size(fromFile,1)]);
        if (fromFile(k,1)<minX)
            minX=fromFile(k,1);
        end
        if (fromFile(k,2)<minY)
            minY=fromFile(k,2);
        end
        if (fromFile(k,1)>maxX)
            maxX=fromFile(k,1);
        end
        if (fromFile(k,2)>maxY)
            maxY=fromFile(k,2);
        end
        toc
    end
    [thisFile,remaining]=strtok(remaining);
end
```

As can be seen, I've added a tic-toc, and the time was 3.36secs for one operation!

Any suggestion on, why this is so slow, and how to improve the speed.. I need to order 2x6,000,000 lines, and I can't be bothered to wait 466 days.. :D

Best regards
Mark

Comment: Use the built in profiler. It will give you a line by line profile so you can see exactly where the time is being spent.

Comment: Hi.. According to the profiler, the for-loop should take less than 0.01 seconds.. The size of the fromFile array is about 700000x3, for the file in question, so I guess the it's slow due to extracting data 3 times from that array.. Can this be improved? Or would I be better of, importing the data in another way?

Comment: I'm not sure you're looking in the right place. Look for the red lines - these are taking more time (the for loop definition line shouldnt take long because that is just timing the comparison on each iteration). I think you could probably vectorise away the loop over k (take maxes + mins on the whole loaded array). Also if you can control where the data is coming from make sure its not compressed if load time is an issue (should see from the profiler)

Comment: I tried to optimize the expected array size, and also the borders, so now I use an expected array of 10000x10000, which seems to be so much faster! So I guess the lesson learned is that array-sizes really needs to be as limited as possible.. :) Thanks for you so much for your help.. :)

Comment: Mark, can you upload an example data file? There are a couple things you can do to increase*significantly* but details will depend on the contents of the data file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a **sparse** matrix?

A sparse matrix in matlab is defined by a list of values and their location in the matrix -
incidentally this matches your input file perfectly.

While this representation is generally meant for matrices which are truly sparse, (i.e. most of their values are zeros), it appears that in your case it would be much faster to load the matrix using the sparse function even if it is not truly sparse.

Since your data is organised in such a way (location of every data point) my guess is it is sparse anyway.

The function to create a sparse matrix takes the location as columns so instead of a for loop your code will look something like this (this segment replaces the whole for loop):

```
minX = min(fromFile(:,1);
maxX = max(fromFile(:,1);
minY = min(fromFile(:,2);
minY = max(fromFile(:,2);
S = sparse(fromFile(:,1) - borderX, fromFile(:,2) - borderY, fromFile(:,3));
```

Note that the other change I've made is calculating minimum / maximum values directly from the matrix - this is much faster than going over a for loop, as operating on vectors and matrices unleashes the true power of matlab :)

You can perform all sorts of operations on the sparse matrix, but if you want to convert it to a regular matrix you can use the matlab `full` function.

More information [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html) and [there](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f6-8856.html).